# Simple Access w\Read&Write to XML file using Android

Tags: android, xml

I'm new to android development, and I'm trying to work a very simple database solution. I have a max of five variables I want to store when the app is installed, and I want the user to be able to change these variables and their changes be remembered after they've closed the app. While I could use the built in SQLite feature, that's way more complex than I need.

Normally in other languages, like VB, C#, and Javascript, I just load the XML into an XML object and then navigate the nodes. Is there any way to do that in android? This solution should only be a dozen or so lines of code within a single class.

If this isn't possible, what is the simplest way to store and retrieve simple data?

Comment: Google "android write xml" or "android read xml". Found a good link at http://www.anddev.org/write_a_simple_xml_file_in_the_sd_card_using_xmlserializer-t8350.html and http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/c0bcc28612617380?pli=1

Answer (score 2):

This is a common question and of course there is a way. Use [Simple XML](http://simple.sourceforge.net). I [wrote a blog post](http://robertmassaioli.wordpress.com/2011/04/21/simple-xml-in-android-1-5-and-up/) on how to make that happen.

Essentially the Simple XML library lets you marshal and un-marshal XML to and from Java Classes by correctly annotating them with Simple XML Annotations. Just read the simple tutorial and my blog post to understand what I mean.